# Write properties file on Android

Tags: android, properties, assets

Following this android's [Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) I created   method to write data on a properties file .

My properties file is inside `asset` folder, with 2 other properties files:

[image]

This is settings.properties file:

```
#DEBUG
debugMode = false

#WIZARD
showWizard = true
```

This is my method (inside an `AppCompatActivity`):

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("showWizard", false);
  editor.commit();
```

The problem is that when I try to read the field "showWizard" I always get true, but when I edit the field "showWizard" with the method above, I don't get any error and it seems that the field was correctly turned from "true" to "false". But it isn't!

Does anybody understand where is my error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Following this android's Guide I created method to write data on a properties file .

The word "properties" does not appear on [that page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

> Does anybody understand where is my error?

Those properties files that you have in `assets/` have absolutely nothing to do with `SharedPreferences`. If you want to read an asset, use `AssetManager` and its `open()` method. That will give you an `InputStream` that you can pass to `load()` on a `Properties` object.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create the settings.properties beforehand. Just remove the .properties files, they might prevent Android from overwriting the data.